# How can I dump DisplayList

Tags: graphics, render, surfaceflinger, displaylist

Looking at the source code, after changing DEBUG_DISPLAY_LIST to 1, you can see all DisplayList prints from logcat, but I can’t see any DisplayList prints after modification. Is there any way for me to dump all DisplayLists before rendering?

```
#frameworks/base/libs/hwui/Debug.h
// Turn on to dump display list state
#define DEBUG_DISPLAY_LIST 0
```

I try the following:

1. Change DEBUG_DISPLAY_LIST to 1
2. make libhwui
3. Replace the libhwui.so file on the device
4. Restart the device

I expected to see all DisplayList prints from logcat, but I didn't.
I'm using a build of Android 12.

```
#frameworks/base/libs/hwui/Debug.h
// Turn on to dump display list state
#define DEBUG_DISPLAY_LIST 1
```